# Printing integer value with %f format specifier

Tags: c, printf

How the first `printf` affects the second `printf` in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", 12.5);

    printf("%f\n", 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Here why does the second `printf` print `12.500000` instead of `3.00000`. Why I am getting input of first `printf` as output of second `printf`. Here I am using gcc compiler for execution.

Comment: As any beginners book or tutorial or class should have taught you, `%d` is for integer values of type `int`, and `%f` is for floating-point values of type `double`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Just replace `printf("%f\n", 3);` with `printf("%f\n", 3.);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior: you first pass a `double` value where `printf` expects an `int`, then you pass an `int` where `printf` expects to receive a `double` value.  Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including what you observe.

A tentative explanation is `double` values and `int` values are passed in a different way (eg: different registers or different places on the stack), and it seems on your architecture the `double` value passed to the first `printf` was not modified by `printf` and is still there when the second `printf` call is evaluated. Hence the second `printf` finds the value `12.5` where it looks for the argument for `%f` format and outputs the same string.

This is by no means guaranteed, anything else can happen, on a different system, with a different compiler or different settings, or a different time or for no reason at all.

You should use sanity warning levels (eg: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`) to detect silly errors like these.

You can print integers with `printf` `%f` format, but you must convert the int argument to `double` values in the call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", 12.5);

    printf("%f\n", (double)3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12.500000
3.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using wrong format specifiers, your code is showing "undefined behaviour". Use %f for floating points and %d for integers, 12.5 is a floating number and 3 is an integer number.

Below is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  
    printf("%f\n", 12.5);  // Use %f for floating-point numbers
    printf("%d\n", 3);     // Use %d for integers

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While your code does provide the correct format specifiers for the types, your answer doesn't really address the OP's question about *why* they are seeing the behaviour they do.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, I have edited and addressed OP's question in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing wrong format specifiers, you used %f on at the value of integer and %d at the value of double. you can change it like below:

```
printf("%f\n", 12.5); 
printf("%d\n", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only answer this by inspecting the compiled binary of your code.

The problem is that you invoke **Undefined Behaviour** by using the wrong format specifiers.
Undefined Behaviour means that the program can't guarantee to work correctly.
It *can* work correctly, but the outcome is actually not defined/predictable.
It might not work at all and crash on a different machine.